# run-time error '-2147417484 (80010108)'

Tags: excel, vba

Excel inconsistently crashes when i ececute macro. Every time i call a various macros, excel may crash, and it invokes that error:

run-time error '-2147417484 (80010108)'

when i go to debug, it goes directly to the line that have that code: 
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

this line exists in many macro of the excel file.

Which is strange is that every time the code crashes, i cannot see the cell or lines that a have selected, but i can modify the content, without seeing what i have modified.

The only way to refresh the screen is by closing excel and opening it up again.

need help plz

here is the file, to execute the macro, go to page global, and click on either of the buttons, the macro should crash

https://www.dropbox.com/s/f1sjkh4twfdmuuu/Gabari%20plan%20de%20vente.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: No thanks - I'm not going to download a macro enabled file for (hopefully) obvious reasons.  Instead, can you post the relevant parts of your code here, for our review?  Also, please read [How to avoid using `.Select`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) as it can cause many headaches.

Comment: show the code you have, and not in a download link pls. I won't register my email adress to every posible site on the planet, shame (for obvious reasons too)

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of this kind of problem is file corruption.

reboot your machine, the do the following below:

Copy your code into either notepad or notepad++, delete the code modules, create new ones, then copy your code from notepad back into the new modules.

see if that doesn't help.